# Приведение типов

Tags: javascript

```
m = [ 0 ];
r = ( m == !m );
// r = true!;
```

Почему так получается?

Такой же результат можно получить так: `m.toString() == Boolean( !m )`

Comment: и где принятый вами ответ?..

Comment: Как принять то - чего нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прочёл спецификацию [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)... Оказывается, в реальности выполняются следующие действия:

```
arr = [0];
b = !arr;

arr == b ?:
  Object:arr == Boolean:b
  Object:arr == Number( Boolean:b )
  String:(Object:arr).toString() == Number( Boolean:b )
  Number( String:(Object:arr).toString() ) == Number( Boolean:b )
  Number( '0' ) == Number( false )
  0 == 0
  true
```

Answer (score 1):

приведу код из консоли =)

```
m = [ 0 ];
[0]
m
[0]
!m
false
m == !m
true
m.toString()
"0"
!m.toString()
false
"0" == false
true
```

по моему, когда вызывается оператор сразвнения ==, то вызывается методы **toString()** у обоих операндов, а значение **"0"** и **false** как мы видим считаются эквивалентными =)

Comment: **`(false).toString() = 'false'`** и **`'false'!='0'`**, так что **toString** вызывается только у массива<br>
NOT == false всех для всех объектов!<br>
Кстати, очень примечательно, что **`!('0') === false`**

Comment: да вобщем это не важно, главно что у массива вызвался toString и появилось "0". !m дает нам false
а вот теперь сравниваются "0" == false и интерпретатор дает true этому выражению.

Answer (score -1):

Простите не знаю javascript. Но может быть потому, что компилятор не знает, что такое "не ноль", а сравнивать он должен **численные** значения. То же самое и во втором Вашем варианте.